# Does Irrlicht need OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, irrlicht

I have built Irrlicht with _IRR_COMPILE_WITH_OPENGL_ option off. And then I have included such an Irrlicht to my program. When I try to start it, it gives an error:

> No OpenGL support compiled in.

Why does this problem occur? I have read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrlicht_Engine#Features), that Irrlicht has internal rasterizers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured it out by myself, Irrlicht doesn't need OpenGL, but this problem occurs, because the device type in createDevice function was set to video::EDT_OPENGL. If Irrlicht should use its own rasterizers, it must be set to video::EDT_SOFTWARE.